# Correct formula giving "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined" error when running sub

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

I want to paste formula's in column B with a delay in between. The formula should only paste the formula if the cell left to it (in case of B1 this is A1) is not empty, like this:

[image]

I have the following VBA that pastes the formula with a delay of 1 sec.

```
    Option Explicit

Sub RetrieveDataDelay()
'paste formulas into cells, then calculate, then delay rinse repeat

    '=========================
    'Declare Variables
    '=========================
        Dim i As Long 'used to loop
        Dim rowCount As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long 'used to find the last row

    '=========================
    'Setup for Speed
    '=========================
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    '=========================
    'Define Variables
    '=========================
        LastRow = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'This will find the last used row in column A, change the number 1 to whatever column number you want
        rowCount = 1 ' set to how many rows you want to do at a time

    '=========================
    'Do Work
    '=========================
        For i = 1 To LastRow Step rowCount
            Range("B" & i, "B" & WorksheetFunction.Min(i + rowCount - 1, LastRow)).Formula = "'=IF(ISBLANK(A" & i & ");" & """" & """" & ";Dump(Volumes(A" & i & ";2528;1010;TRUE;" & "Volume" & ";TRUE)))" 'set the formula to whatever it needs to be
                Calculate
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 'this delays 1 second
        Next i

    '=========================
    'Setup for Speed - Reverse
    '=========================
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

The error occurs at this part

```
Range("B" & i, "B" & WorksheetFunction.Min(i + rowCount - 1, LastRow)).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(A" & i & ");" & """" & """" & ";Dump(Volumes(A" & i & ";2528;1010;TRUE;" & "Volume" & ";TRUE)))"
```

The errors has something to due with the formula, which it does not accept. This is a custom formula used with an excel extension. I know that the formula works, as I put a single quotation mark in front as such:

```
Range("B" & i, "B" & WorksheetFunction.Min(i + rowCount - 1, LastRow)).Formula = "'=IF(ISBLANK(A" & i & ");" & """" & """" & ";Dump(Volumes(A" & i & ";2528;1010;TRUE;" & "Volume" & ";TRUE)))"
```

so that it pastes the formally literally. If I then remove the quotation mark from the formula the formula works. So the questions remains why it doesn't accept this specific formula in the VBA.

Using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

`Range.Formula` needs the formula notation always in en_us format independent of the current locale settings. That means functions in English language and also comma as delimiter between formula parameters and not semicolon.

So

```
.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(A" & i & ")," & """" & """" & ",Dump(Volumes(A" & i & ",2528,1010,TRUE," & "Volume" & ",TRUE)))"
```

After setting `Range.Formula`, the locale settings will be nevertheless active in the sheet. So in the sheet the formula will be delimited with semicolons if so set.

Btw.: The complicated string notation for double quotes is not neccessary.

```
.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(A" & i & "),"""",Dump(Volumes(A" & i & ",2528,1010,TRUE," & "Volume" & ",TRUE)))"
```

Comment: You sir, are a hero. That worked.

Do you have any idea why this VBA is so slow? I just tested it on 50 rows, it takes nearly 2 minutes when I set the VBA at 1 row at a time. When I set if on 10 rows at a times it does it in 46 seconds. But 10 rows at a time should be 5 times with a delay on one second, so I would think this would be under 10 seconds..

Comment: In my opinion. the speed is mainly determined of the time `Calculate` takes. And this is mainly determined of your `UDF` `Dump` which is unknown for me. So I dont know why it is slow. But why the `For` loop at all? Why not simply `Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"""",Dump(Volumes(A1,2528,1010,TRUE,Volume,TRUE)))"` and then `Calculate` only once?